# django how to count quantity of objects of a class in a database

Tags: python, django

How to count quantity of objects of a class `Record` in a `sqlite3` database connected to one certain object of the class `Subject`. I created new objects in `django-admin`.

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Record(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject)
    record_short_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Record.objects.filter(subject=subject_instance).count()
```

Or like that - `subject_instance.record_set.count()`. 
Andrew Gorcester has the point.

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count

Comment: why the second one is better?

Comment: I can't comment on the perfomance difference, still that approach looks a bit more 'native' to me. Removed the 'better' so it not confuses anybody.

Comment: As a side note, if you use `filter(subject_id=subject_instance.pk)`, django won't make a join to get the id to filter on.

Comment: @kroolik My experience has been that Django won't make a join regardless of which one of those you to -- it is smart enough to just do the primary key lookup.

Comment: @AndrewGorcester, sorry for misleading - I was convinced it did some time ago.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your instance is called `sub`:

```
sub.record_set.count()
```

The foreign key on Record automatically creates a backwards reference called record_set.  You can customize that name by using the `related_name` argument to `models.ForeignKey()`.  For instance, `subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, related_name="records")`, and then `sub.records.count()`